# How to use INDEX and AGGREGATE with multiple reference numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a sort of process matrix in excel.  Basically, I want to fill in a single query, have that query return multiple results, then feed those results back into the query--returning a second level of results.

I'm using an index aggregate function on a single box (I6) to return multiple results in a column (I9:I30)

```
=INDEX($E$2:$E$299,AGGREGATE(15,3,($B$2:$B$299=$I$6)/($B$2:$B$299=$I$6)*(ROW($B$2:$B$299)-ROW($B$1)),ROWS($H$9:H9)))
```

I tried to put results back into the query by replacing I6 references with I9:I30, but the resulting is not returning anything.

Basically, I just want the results from the first fed back into the index aggregate

Comment: It would help if you would mock up some simple example of the data and expected output.  Then [edit] the question and post that example for us to reference.